# Cropper is not a function

Tags: jquery, symfony, webpack

On my symfony project with webpack encore, I am using PrestaImageBundle https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaImageBundle , I have installed cropper, as stated in the documentation https://github.com/fengyuanchen/jquery-cropper#installation but when uploading the image I ended up with this error in my console :

cropper.js:158 Uncaught TypeError: this.$container.$preview.children(...).cropper is not a function
at Cropper../vendor/presta/image-bundle/Resources/public/js/cropper.js.Cropper.prepareCropping (cropper.js:158)
at FileReader.reader.onload (cropper.js:72)

There are no 404 error, only this one when uploading an image.

It should give me the option to crop the image to the desired size.

here are links and config used :

in base template :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

in twig config :

```
twig:
default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
```

in js file :

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min';
import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.min';
import 'jquery-cropper/dist/jquery-cropper.min.js';
import * as Cropper from '../../vendor/presta/image-bundle/Resources/public/js/cropper.js';
import '../css/form.scss';
```

in css file :

```
@import "/../../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min";
@import '../../vendor/presta/image-bundle/Resources/public/css/cropper.css';
```

If any of you has an idea why I end up with this error, please let me know, We have read documentation several times and still don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: What does `this.$container.$preview` return? is it a jQuery object?

Comment: yes it's a jquery object, and the code is from the bundle "image-bundle"

Comment: My guess is you need to loop over the children order to do a `new Cropper` for each one as is done in the docs

Comment: Thank you and sorry I didn't share this part of the code in the file JS :    
 ```(function(w, $) {

    'use strict';

    $(function() {
        $('.cropper').each(function() {
            new Cropper($(this));
        });
    });

})(window, jQuery);```                                                                                                So, there is a "new Cropper" for each children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself, the answer was in the webpack.config file : https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html (you have to uncommented a line and wepack Encore will can read a jQuery plugin)